# Is it wise to provide access to weak_ptr in a library interface?

Tags: c++, boost, weak-ptr

I have written a library that exposes references to several related object types.  All of these objects have their lifetimes managed by the library internally via `boost::shared_ptr`

A user of the library would also be able to know, by nature of the library, the lifetimes of any of the exposed objects.  So they could store pointers or keep references to these objects.  It would be reasonable for them to do this and know when those objects are no longer valid.

But I feel guilty forcing my users to be reasonable.

**Is it acceptable to have a library expose `weak_ptr`'s to its objects?  Have other libraries done this?**

I have profiled this library's usage in apps and have found it to be too mission-critical to expose `weak_ptr` exclusively.

**Would it be wiser to have matching API functions expose either a reference *or* a weak_ptr or to make any object capable of exposing a `weak_ptr` to itself?**

Comment: You're asking us if you should expose weak_ptrs, but then you say that profiling reveals that you can't use weak_ptrs everywhere -- right? What would you provide instead for those performance-critical cases? A raw reference? Or a shared_ptr?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The library already exposes references.  I'm considering matching API functions that expose either a reference or a weak_ptr.

Comment: Hmm. I guess you're suggesting weak_ptrs instead of shared_ptrs because you're trying to get the calling code to detect mistakes, right? But I think that the calling code needs to convert that weak_ptr to a shared_ptr anyway, so you don't buy much protection with them -- quite possibly, the...

Comment: ... caller will just immediately lock() the weak_ptr you passed back, and use that shared_ptr ever after. For weak_ptrs to be useful, you would have to assume that (a) the caller might try to use the object at the wrong time but (b) he will try to lock() the weak_ptr each time before using it.

Comment: So, since a weak_ptr only catches a "not-too-badly-misbehaving" caller, I'd probably just stick with shared_ptrs and/or raw refs. But I can't see a strong argument against weak_ptrs other than that they won't catch every form of misuse (i.e. just-lock()-it-right-away-and-use-that-forever misuse).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: My understanding of weak_ptr is that it doesn't manage the lifetime of the object, which is what I want, and can detect if what it's pointing to has been deleted, which I also want. That's really all I want and shared_ptr doesn't do those things.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: A user could lock the weak_ptr indefinitely as you say, but that would be a very poor use of weak_ptr's

Comment: OK, if detecting whether the pointee has been deleted is what you want, weak_ptr is a good choice. Alternatively you might be able to get the information you need from calling unique() or use_count() in shared_ptr<T>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `smart_ptr`s are already directly accessible to the library's users, then they've already got access to the `weak_ptr`s, simply via the corresponding `weak_ptr`'s constructor. But if the `smart_ptr`s are all internal to the library, that's a different story.

In that case, I'd recommend letting each object pass out `weak_ptr`s to itself, in addition to any other access your library offers. That gives the users the most flexibility: if they need a `weak_ptr`, they've got immediate access to it; if they need a `shared_ptr`, they can easily get it; and if they just need access to the object itself, they can ignore the smart pointers entirely.

Of course, I don't know what your library does or how it's used or designed. That might change my recommendation.

Comment: The library currently uses shared_ptr internally only.

Answer (score 4):

Coming up with convoluted mechanisms to get at the objects of your library will only result in people not using your library.  If the semantics of the library dictate you need to have people using weak_ptrs, there no way around the user knowing that the objects may go away at some point.  Make the interface express as much information about the usage of the library as possible, keeps documentation down and makes it infinitely easier to use.

You can't design around bad/inexperienced users.

Answer (score 2):

If you give your clients access to `weak_ptr`s they can just lock them to create `shared_ptr`s and end up delaying the destruction of objects.  That might cause problems with your library.

I suggest wrapping a `weak_ptr` in some other class and giving the caller a `shared_ptr` to that.  That way they can't just call `weak_ptr<T>::lock()`.  You seem to have performance constraints that might influence how you implement it, but a `shared_ptr<InterfaceClass>` might be a good way to go, and keep the class with the `weak_ptr` internal to your library.

That way you also keep these implementation details out of your library interface and you can change the way you implement it without changing your interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with exposing weak_ptrs, especially given that [TR1 has similar smart pointers](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2005/n1745.pdf) (PDF).

TR1 is largely implemented by Visual Studio and GCC, but not some of the other compilers out there.  But when it's implemented in all the compilers you care about, you may want to rework the API to expose those smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both trap invalid use of the library (trying to access the objects when they have been deleted) as well as have a high-performance API (no weak_ptr's and shared_ptr's in the API), then you could consider have a different API for debug and nondebug builds.

Let's suppose for simplicity that you have only one class of objects you expose; call this class Object. The pointer type which you return from the API for accessing the internal objects is then defined as:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
typedef ObjectPtrFacade ObjectPtr 
#else
typedef Object * ObjectPtr;
#endif
```

Here the facade is class which you write. It works roughly like this:

```
class ObjectPtrFacade {
public:
    ObjectPtrFacade(Object *o) : wptr(o) { }
    // copy constructor and assignment here etc. (not written)
    Object * operator -> () const { return access(); }
    Object & operator * () const { return *access(); }
private:
    Object * access() { 
      assert(wptr.use_count() > 0);
      return (Object *)(wptr.lock());
    }
    weak_ptr<Object> wptr; 
}
```

In this way, whenever you build a debugging build, you have a special kind of smart pointer in use which asserts before accessing the object that its use_count() is higher than zero, i.e. that the object still exists. If the object has been released, you get a failing assert, which is better than a null pointer reference.

In general of course it is so that using weak_ptr's does not help if you have "stupid" users of the API, because they could call lock() and then still make a null-pointer reference after the weak_ptr returns a shared_ptr which is empty...